# A pretty much simple number theory problem

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Let $x$ be an irrational number, and $n$ be a positive integer.
Will there ever be a set of $(n,x)$ which satisfies
$x(n-x) \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

If so, could you suggest those numbers?
And, if not, could you prove why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

- Suppose $x(n-x)=m$.  Then express $x$ in terms of $n$ and $m$.
- Can you find an example where $n$ and $m$ are integers (and $n$ positive) but $x$ irrational?
- Remember that square roots of non-square positive integers are irrational

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example
$$n=3$$
$$m=1$$
$$x=\frac12\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)$$

This is what happens if you simplify it.
$$\frac12\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)\left(3-\frac12\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)$$
$$\frac32\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)-\left(\frac12\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)\right)^2$$
$$\frac32\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)-\frac14\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)^2$$
$$\frac32\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)-\frac14\left(14+6\sqrt{5}\right)$$
$$\frac32\left(3+\sqrt{5}\right)-3.5-\frac32\sqrt{5}$$
$$\frac92+\frac32\sqrt{5}-3.5-\frac32\sqrt{5}$$
$$1+\frac32\sqrt{5}-\frac32\sqrt{5}$$
$$1$$

Answer (score 0):

I already posted an answer with an example, but I decided to make a different answer which shows how you can find these values.

$$x(n-x)=m$$
Lets solve for $x$
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x(n-x)=m\\
-x^2+nx=m\\
x^2-nx=-m\\
x^2-nx+\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2=\frac{n^2}{4}-m\\
\left(x-\frac{n}{2}\right)^2=\frac{n^2}{4}-m\\
4\left(x-\frac{n}{2}\right)^2=n^2-4m\\
2x-n=\pm\sqrt{n^2-4m}\\
2x=n\pm\sqrt{n^2-4m}\\
x=\frac12\left(n\pm\sqrt{n^2-4m}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$
This gives us 2 values of $x$ for each $(n,m)$
This $x$ is going to be irrational when $\sqrt{n^2-4m}$ is irrational.
This implies that if $x$ is irrational then $n^2-4m$ is not a perfect square.

Conclusion:

$x(n-x)=m$ has 2 irrational values of $x$ which solves the equation for each pair of $(m,n)$ where $n^2-4m$ is not a perfect square.